# Class method and argument passing

Tags: c++, class, methods

I have been programming and I have spotted strange behavior in c++ classes. So I made simple class that contains string, constructor for that class and friend method(show) that prints string from object. But as you can see in main function. I pass to method(show) simple string and it works.
I found it convenient, but why it worked if method parameter is reference to an object?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class lol
{
  char * str;
public:
  lol(const char * s);
  friend void show(const lol & l);
};

lol::lol(const char * s)        //assign string to object
{
  str = new char[strlen(s)+1];
  strcpy(str,s);
}

void show(const lol & l)        //prints string from object
{   
  cout << l.str;
};

int main()
{
  show("TEST"); //passing string but not an object
  return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I found it convenient, but why it worked if method parameter is reference to an object?

It works because your `lol` class defines a constructor accepting a `const char*` and which is *not* marked as `explicit`.

This authorizes the compiler to resolve the call `show("TEST")` by constructing a temporary object of type `lol`, passing the string literal `"TEST"` as the argument to the constructor, and binding your reference argument `l` to this temporary object.

To prevent implicit *user-defined conversion sequences* of this kind, mark your constructor as `explicit`:

```
class lol
{
    char * str;
public:
    explicit lol(const char * s);
//  ^^^^^^^^
    friend void show(const lol & l);
};
```

This way, the call `show("TEST")` [will result in a compiler error](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48Ihhx$2).

Comment: Thank you. What was confusing is that it worked with references. Now I understood.